# Scala TypeTag missing class name

Tags: scala, generics, reflection

I'm trying to get some information using Scala's reflect library :

```
abstract class Model

class Person extends Model

class Car extends Model

abstract class AbstractDao[T <: Model]

object PersonDao extends AbstractDao[Person]

object CarDao extends AbstractDao[Car]

object DataLoader {

  val daos = Seq(PersonDao, CarDao)
  val modelToString = daos.map(genericImportEntities(_))

  val modelToString2 = Seq(genericImportEntities(PersonDao), genericImportEntities(CarDao))

  private def genericImportEntities[T <: Model](dao: AbstractDao[T])
                                               (implicit
                                                t2: TypeTag[T]
                                               ): String = {

    t2.tpe.toString
  }
}
```

If I call modelToString, the output is 
    List(_1, _1)

With modelToString2, it is 
    List(Person, Car)

Any idea how can I make modelToString work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that type of `daos` is `Seq[AbstractDao[_]]`. So when calling `daos.map(genericImportEntities(_))`, `T` is an unknown type which the compiler calls `_1`. Generally, `TypeTag`s are only useful when you know the static types at the point where the compiler should insert them, and in this case you don't.

The easiest way to fix this would be to move `TypeTag` into `AbstractDao`:

```
abstract class AbstractDao[T <: Model](implicit val tag: TypeTag[T])

private def genericImportEntities[T <: Model](dao: AbstractDao[T]) = 
  dao.tag.tpe.toString
```

Then the compiler inserts the tags at definition of `PersonDao` and `CarDao` and they can be used later in `genericImportEntities`.